# Evaluate Elixir command from cmdline - module is not available

Tags: erlang, elixir, elixir-iex

I’m finding that if I do the following everything works as expected:

```
$ iex --sname console --remsh eprocess@service
eprocess@service)1> MyModule.process()
```

However, `MyModule` is not available if I try:

```
$ iex --sname console --remsh eprocess@$HOSTNAME -e "MyModule.process()"
```

The error is:

> ** (UndefinedFunctionError) function MyModule.process/0 is undefined (module
>   MyModule is not available)

Does anyone know how to include dependencies from mix when using the `-e` flag?

Comment: You could try adding the alias into the expression to evaluate--like so: `-e "(alias MyModule; MyModule.process())"` NB due to the way that multiple expressions are evaluated, you need to add parentheses around the expression.

Comment: No luck. Same error persists.

Comment: The `-S` parameter specifies a script to run.  You should be able to create a script--for example `runmyprocess.exs` and then add `-S runmyprocess` to the end of your commandline.

Comment: Same issue. I don't think my my application specific modules are loaded into iex when the "-e" or "-S" params are evaluated.

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci I managed to overcome the import issue by writing a script that adds `-pa */ebin` for every dependency I have. However, the call I want to make is DB dependent so it's saying that the repo is not started. I manually call Mix.Ecto.ensure_started(Repo), but now it says that the configs are not specified. I'm really not sure what to do...

Comment: In fact, here's something interesting:

`iex --sname console --remsh eprocess@$HOSTNAME -e "IO.inspect(Application.get_env(:a, :b))"`
-> result: nil

`iex --sname console --remsh eprocess@$HOSTNAME`
`iex> IO.inspect(Application.get_env(:a, :b)`
-> result: not nil

Seems like the command we pass to "-e" doesn't have access to the application's context, but the shell that gets started up afterwards does.